# How to remove the empty rows from TableView Of JAVA FX 2.0

Tags: java, css, tableview, javafx-2

I have been trying to remove the empty rows from table view but i am not able to do that with css which i have read in some blog

here the css is which i am applying on that 
/-------------------------------------------------

```
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

/-------------------------------------------------

But iam getting the error

/------------------------------------

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin' for control TableView@125ff34[styleClass=table-view table-row-cell]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_cssSet(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_cssSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$2900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for TableView@125ff34[styleClass=table-view table-row-cell]
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------

Does anybody have idea how to resolve it? or any other way to remove the empty rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your css worked for with JavaFX 2.1. Try next:

- update to JavaFX 2.1
- remove everything from your css file except these classes

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @sergey i will try what u said and come up with if i got any problem.

Comment: iam still getting the same error i think the cause of this is iam creating the table view in other class where there is no scene and iam returning the pane from there and setting the style in main class. Could u explain me how should i do?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution :
inside your css file add this :

```
.table-row-cell:empty:odd, .table-row-cell:empty:even {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

tested and worked for me

[Click to show my tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nYz7.png)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.